# Angular - Select inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem with selects inside ng-repeat, the problem is that every select I create inside a ng-repeat are disabled, if I try to open the dropdown it doesn't show the options.

Select are generated in ng-repeat and the number of selects and all values are 
in a JSON.

I think the problem could be the selects's ng-model, i must assign dynamically an ng-model but i don't know how.

This is the code (i don't include the service that get the JSON, but it works for sure)

JSON

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":1,
      "Name":"Tipo Fuga",
      "Values":[  
         {  
            "Name":"Tipo Fuga",
            "Value":"Week End in Famiglia",
            "Id":10555
         },
         {  
            "Name":"Tipo Fuga",
            "Value":"Fuga romantica",
            "Id":10560
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Id":2,
      "Name":"Localita",
      "Values":[  
         {  
            "Name":"Localita",
            "Value":"Al mare",
            "Id":111
         },
         {  
            "Name":"Localita",
            "Value":"In montagna",
            "Id":112
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Id":3,
      "Name":"Num Notti",
      "Values":[  
         {  
            "Name":"Num Notti",
            "Value":"1",
            "Id":11076
         },
         {  
            "Name":"Num Notti",
            "Value":"2",
            "Id":11077
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Id":4,
      "Name":"Tipo Soggiorno",
      "Values":[  
         {  
            "Name":"Tipo Soggiorno",
            "Value":"1 stella",
            "Id":1100
         },
         {  
            "Name":"Tipo Soggiorno",
            "Value":"2 stelle",
            "Id":1101
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ricercaAttivita">
    <div ng-repeat="masterAttribute in masterAttributes">
        <select ng-model="selected-attr" ng-options="attr.Id as attr.Value for attr in masterAttribute.Values">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
tantoSvagoApp.controller("ricercaAttivita", function ($scope, $http, serviceRicercaAttivita) {

    var parametersMaster = {"Id": master};
    serviceRicercaAttivita.getMasterAttributes(parametersMaster, 
    successCallBackMasterAttributes);

    function successCallBackMasterAttributes(result) {
            $scope.masterAttributes = result;
    }
});
```

EDIT

I tried to do a simple thing, i created a select with static options inside a div and of course it works fine:

```
<div>
  <select>
    <option value="">TUTTE</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

If i put the ng-repeat directive in the  select doesn't work, it mean that i can't open the dropdown and then select the option.

```
<div ng-repeat="masterAttribute in masterAttributes">
  <select>
    <option value="">TUTTE</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Declare your ng-model as an array and change your ng-model to selected-attr[$index] and see if it is working?

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement seems ambiguous.

`ng-model` can be a new property in the JSON which holds the selected `id` from the `select`.

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
app.controller("ricercaAttivita", function($scope) {
  $scope.masterAttributes = [{
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "Tipo Fuga",
      "Values": [{
          "Name": "Tipo Fuga",
          "Value": "Week End in Famiglia",
          "Id": 10555
        },
        {
          "Name": "Tipo Fuga",
          "Value": "Fuga romantica",
          "Id": 10560
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "Localita",
      "Values": [{
          "Name": "Localita",
          "Value": "Al mare",
          "Id": 111
        },
        {
          "Name": "Localita",
          "Value": "In montagna",
          "Id": 112
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "Name": "Num Notti",
      "Values": [{
          "Name": "Num Notti",
          "Value": "1",
          "Id": 11076
        },
        {
          "Name": "Num Notti",
          "Value": "2",
          "Id": 11077
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 4,
      "Name": "Tipo Soggiorno",
      "Values": [{
          "Name": "Tipo Soggiorno",
          "Value": "1 stella",
          "Id": 1100
        },
        {
          "Name": "Tipo Soggiorno",
          "Value": "2 stelle",
          "Id": 1101
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="ricercaAttivita">
  <div ng-repeat="masterAttribute in masterAttributes">
    <select ng-model="masterAttribute.Selected" ng-options="attr.Id as attr.Value for attr in masterAttribute.Values">
        </select>
  </div>
  <pre>{{masterAttributes | json}}</pre>

</body>
```

Comment: i tried to set ng-model="masterAttribute.Id", but the selects are disabled and i don't understand why

Comment: You cannot set  `ng-model="masterAttribute.Id"` since its already a property of the object. What do you mean by selects are disabled?

Comment: i mean that the dropdowns does not open, but if i see the source code i see all the options

Comment: maybe i did't understand how i can set the ng-model

Comment: i edited my post with a simple example, i hope that it can help